# How to specify a callback in activerecord that is only called when the record is created or a certain field is updated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

I'm working on a small checkbook balancing webapp to teach myself rails. Account has a `balance` field, which I would like to update when any of the the related `Transaction.amount` fields are changed/created. I'm looking through the docs, but I'm having a hard time visualizing how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should employ an observer to do the job. Please checkout the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html).

Comment: ooh, this looks like it may just be what I need. Thanks!